# The code to be executed should be placed within a default function that is exported by the global script

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, stenciljs

Following: https://stenciljs.com/pwa

I tried this multiple times

git clone https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-pwa-toolkit my-pwa

```
Run npm install

Run npm run build

Run nmp start
```

Global Script

The code to be executed should be placed within a default function that is exported by the global script. Ensure all of the code in the global script is wrapped in the function() that is exported.

./node_modules\ionicons\dist\collection\global.js

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

You had to rebuild and re-pull the packages and ran again and it started working.